# Removendo um tab-content e adicionando class active ao que possuir conteúdo

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Possuo uma tablist na página que é responsável por pegar alguns conteúdos através de uma `function`. Quando essa `function` não retorna nenhum valor, o certo é dar um `hide` nessa `list` e no seu `content`. Até ai tudo está funcionando, veja o código abaixo:

```
var explore = $('#tablist-explore');
if ( $.trim($('#tablist-explore ul').html()).length == 0 ){
    $('#explore-tablist').hide();
}
```

Esse, no caso, é o responsável por remover o elemento, caso ele não tenha uma `child`, mas ai vem minha grande dúvida...

Eu tenho 5 tabs, a primeira dela é a que possui a `class active` por padrão, porém em algumas partes do projeto essa primeira `tab` não possui conteúdo e a próxima `tab` não pega a classe `active`.

Vejam os exemplos do que estou dizendo:

- Apaga as tabs que não possuem conteúdo: http://prntscr.com/95zidn (Aqui ele possui 4 de 5 tabs, ou seja, um parte funciona)
- Apaga as tabs, mas não ativa a que está presente: http://prntscr.com/95ziy8 (Aqui ele possui uma única tab, mas não recebe a class active)

Resumindo tudo: Como eu faço para jogar uma classe `active` dentro da tab que o conteúdo não for 0 ou nulo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desenvolvi uma alternativa para sua necessidade, vamos ver oque ela faz?

Este script irá varrer todas as tabs, que neste caso é a `<div class="tab-child">`, verificando se possui filho, caso possua, irá verificar se este filho possui  valor, se sim adicionará a classe `active` a tab. Se nenhuma das validações for verdadeira vai para a próxima tab.

```js
var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-child');
var isActive = 0;
Array.prototype.forEach.call(tabs, function(childs) {
  var len = childs.children.length;
  if(len > 0 && isActive === 0) {
    for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
      if(childs.children[i].textContent !== '' && isActive === 0) {
        childs.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.tab-container {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.tab-child {
  display: inline-block;;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 30%;
}
.tab-child:hover {
  background-color: lightpink;
}
.tab-child.active {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
}
.tab-child:hover .tab-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tab" class="tab-container">
  <div class="tab-child">
    Tab 1
    <!-- Não existe filho -->
  </div>
  <div class="tab-child">
    Tab 2
    <!-- Existe filho, porem sem valor -->
    <div class="tab-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-child">
    Tab 3
    <!-- Existe filho com valor -->
    <div class="tab-content">existe conteudo na tab 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/pohLagpn/)

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem, a class **active** esta inicializando fixa no primeiro elemento via HTML, certo? Se for isso sugiro que adicione a class de forma mais dinamica com javascript. Faça uma varredura nas tabs e localize todas as que possuem conteúdo *(length)*, destas adicione a class **active** no primeiro elemento.

Comment: Exatamente Fábio, é que por enquanto não tem nem muito o que publicar, o máximo seria HTML e CSS. Eu estou mais confuso na hora de fazer a questão da lógica em quando uma tablist for removida por falta de conteúdo, o código passe uma classe active e um aria-expanded=true pra próxima tab ativa. Entende?